# Getting variables outside executeScript in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, global-variables

I am trying to code a chrome extension, and I have a background.html with this code:

```
var x = "test";

function tabChanged(id, info, tab){
    if(info.status == 'complete'){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {code:"try{alert(x);}catch(e){alert(e);}"}, null);
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(tabChanged);
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null,function(tabs){
    for(var index=0; index < tabs.length; index++){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[index].id, {code:"try{alert(x);}catch(e){alert(e);}"}, null);
    }
});
```

But variable "x" is always undefined inside executeScript.

**How can I get/set x from executeScript?** Without using messaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content scripts executes in context of web page. See [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) section in Chrome docs for more information.

If you want to pass string variable from background page to `chrome.tabs.executeScript` you must do something like this:

```js
var x = "test";
chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {code:"var x = '"+x+"'; try{alert(x);}catch(e){alert(e);}"},null);
```

If you want to modify variable, you have only one way - messaging:

```js
var x = 1;
console.log('x=' + x);

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request);
    if(request.command == 'setVar') {
        window[request.name] = request.data;
    }
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    var code = "chrome.extension.sendRequest({command: 'setVar', name: 'x', data: 2});";
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:code});
    window.setTimeout(function(){console.log('x=' + x);}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Do you have any sample on how to modify the variable?

Comment: Well you said is the only way so yes.

Comment: Check it, but i think it's better to create content script and communicate with background page from it.

Answer (score 0):

For chrome `Chrome 92+`, you can use [args](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection)

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}).then(([tab])=>{
  const para = "Hello world!!!"
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    function: (args) => {
      alert(args)
    },
    args: [para]
  })
})
```

---

or you can use the [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage)

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ]
}
```

```js
chrome.storage.sync.set({msg: "hello world"})
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}).then(([tab])=>{
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    function: () => {
      chrome.storage.sync.get(['msg'], ({msg})=> {
        console.log(`${msg}`)
        alert(`Command: ${msg}`)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

#### Update for pass functions in args is OK?

**You can't**

Neither `Storage` nor `Args`, they both can't accept the function parameter.

Example:

```
const myObj = {
  msg: "Hi",
  myNum: 1,
  myFunc: ()=>{return "hi"},
  myFunc2: function() {return ""}
}

chrome.storage.sync.set({
  msg: "my storage msg",
  myObj,
})

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}).then(([tab])=>{
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    function: (para1, para2MyObj) => {
      console.log(para1) // Hello
      console.log(JSON.stringify(para2MyObj)) // {"msg":"Hi","myNum":1} // myFunc, myFunc2 are missing. You can't get the variable if its type is function.
      chrome.storage.sync.get(['msg', "myObj"], ({msg, myObj})=> {
        console.log(`${msg}`) // "my storage msg"
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj)) // {"msg":"Hi","myNum":1}
        alert(`Command: ${msg}`)
      })
    },
    args: ["Hello", myObj]
  })
})
```

Comment: can we pass functions in args like `args: [function1, function2]` and expect functions working there?

Comment: Hi @xjlin0, I updated my answer hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing those functions as well as my main function in a separated js file, and include that js file by `files: ['filename.js']` under executeScript instead of `function: mainFunction`.

Answer (score -1):

The reason your variable is undefined is because you are referencing your variable inside of a string so you can just simply do this:

```
var yourVar = "your variable"
   //define your variable
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'Your code here' + yourVar + ';}'})
   //then format it like this ({code: "Your code as a string" + your variable + "code"})
```

and if you want to change the variable later than just do the same thing but with your new variable, it's pretty straight forward

Comment: I don't see how that would solve the issue even remotely, and for the same reason the problem exists in the first place. When you use chrome.tabs.executeScript anything in ({code: }) is run in the page and if you simply use a variable it will check the current website for the variable not your script so my work around was to create a string with my variable then eval that so its is no longer a variable but rather part of the string which is then run